# SQL Count condition in main Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, window-functions

I want to pick on those who for the column `is_initial_event`: the values can be 0 or 1. I only want those who have only 1. Not that they have both 1 and 0. There are multiple detail rows for `is_initial_event`.

```
select ac.Full_name, pe.program_start_date, pe.program_end_date, tp.approved_by_Description as 
    Approved, ev.is_initial_event, tp.staff from all_clients_view ac  
inner join program_enrollment_expanded_view pe
    on ac.people_id = pe.people_id
inner join  service_plan_goals_objectives_methods_view tp
    on ac.people_id = tp.people_id
inner join service_plan_event_view ev
    on ac.people_id = ev.people_id
where pe.program_name = 'CFTSS' and tp.Approved_by_description is null
```

Here I tried to add in the count, what I want to count is that if the people_id has > 0 for ev.Is_initial_event = 1 and also has > when ev.IS_initial_event = 0, then I don't want that people_id only when it only has records where ev.is_initial_event = 1 not both.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for window functions?

```
select *
from (
    select 
        ac.Full_name, 
        pe.program_start_date, 
        pe.program_end_date, 
        tp.approved_by_Description as Approved, 
        ev.is_initial_event, 
        tp.staff,
        min(ev.is_initial_event) over(partition by ac.people_id) min_initial_event
    from all_clients_view ac  
    inner join program_enrollment_expanded_view pe
        on ac.people_id = pe.people_id
    inner join service_plan_goals_objectives_methods_view tp
        on ac.people_id = tp.people_id
    inner join service_plan_event_view ev
        on ac.people_id = ev.people_id
    where 
        pe.program_name = 'CFTSS' 
        and tp.Approved_by_description is null
) t
where min_initial_event = 1
```

This returns rows for which all rows having the same `people_id` have `initial_event` set to `1` (note that this assumes that this column contains only `0`s and `1`s, as explained in your question).

Comment: Thanks GMB- what is min_initial_event? should that be min(is_initial_event)

Comment: @PasPalter: that's an alias for the window `min()`, that is defined in the subquery.

Comment: HI it gives an error - Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator.

Comment: @PasPalter: ok so now we know you are using SQL Server, and this column is of ‘BIT‘ datatype. If so, just change `min(ev.is_initial_event)` to `min(ev.is_initial_event + 0)`.

Comment: Just had one question- can we have an or situation that is we would like also the rows that are Null, some are only null not a 1 or 0.